# text/plain not present in mail msg from microsoft account

Tags: email, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, gmail, mime-types

The same message was sent from a microsoft 365 to my microsoft 365 and
to my gmail.  However, `mutt` sees them differently: in the first case

```
I   1   <no description>    [text/html, quoted, windows-1252, 32K]
A   2   somefile        [applica/pdf, base64, 8.4M]
```

while in the second

```
I   1   <no description>    [multipa/alternativ, 7bit, 49K]
I   2   ├─><no description> [text/plain, quoted, windows-1252, 17K]
I   3   └─><no description> [text/html, quoted, windows-1252, 32K]
A   4   somefile        [applica/pdf, base64, 8.4M]
```

I'm using `mbsync` to sync my mail.  The `.muttrc` contains

```
alternative_order text/plain text/enriched text/html
```

I'm wondering where the difference in the two messages' structures (at least as seen by `mutt`) comes from, as I could not find any settings in my employer's microsoft 365 web interface dealing with that, and whether I can do something to fix this, either as end user or escalating this to some admin.

Possible refs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get
https://www.gmass.co/blog/gmail-api-html-plain-text-messages/

Comment: The second email is displayed as `text/plain` ? If so, change alternative_order to: `text/html text/enriched text/plain`

Comment: @Luuk the 2nd email is correctly displayed as text/plain. my issue is with the first email, which is not displayed as text, but as html (only)

Comment: The first mail only contains a `text/html` part, and no `text\plain` part. Mutt does not convert (AFAIK) the html to text.

Comment: You can send an email as text, using office, see: [Change the message format to HTML, Rich Text Format, or plain text](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/change-the-message-format-to-html-rich-text-format-or-plain-text-338a389d-11da-47fe-b693-cf41f792fefa)

Comment: it seems neither mutt, nor mbysnc are involved. maybe gmail made the conversion by itself, not much i can do. (i was on the receiving end, i didn't send the email, cannot contol other people's settings.)